# Clear or update redirect state

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm currently pass data to new page by `Redirect` state from `'react-router-dom'`.
Here is my code:

```
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
...
render() {
    return <Redirect push to={{pathname: "/account/group/" + temp, state: _data}}/>;
}
...
```

And load data on new page `/account/group` successfully:

```
...
constructor(props) {
    super()
    this.state = {
        data: props.location.state,
    }
}
...
```

It's working fine until I try to update the state on new page and send it to the server, then reload the page, this state still take the old value from `props.location.state`, the updated value that seem lost (in fact, this due to I can not change `props.location.state` with new value).

Could anyone can help me with this case? My opinion is change / replace the value of `props.location.state` or clear them?

Thanks all

Comment: how are you updating the state in the new page?

Comment: @azium 
this.state.data = newValue;
this.setState({data: newValue});
The state value do changed but props don't

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of `props.location.state` with new state by this:

```
this.props.history.replace({'pathname': '/account/group/' + _temp, state: newState})
```

From docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/history